# Are there any alternatives to tsocks that support HTTPS proxy?

Tags: proxy, https, transparent-proxy

`tsocks` is using `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to inject into other applications.

I can only access the internet via a HTTPS proxy, however `tsocks` only supports socks proxy.

So is there any alternative that supports HTTPS proxy like proxifier for windows?

Answer (score 1):

i do it exactly by privoxy
also have look at http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/01/msg00086.html 
got a better one: proxychains , believe me, it is the ***exact*** alternative of proxifier

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about command line programs, most of them respect `https_server` environment. You can do the following:

1. Open  `.bashrc` in your home directory (In case you're using another shell, you should open their rc file.)
2. Enter the line `export https_server=https://SERVERADDR:PORT` where `SERVERADDR` is the IP address or hostname of your proxy server and `PORT` is the port.
3. Save the file and type `source $HOME/.bashrc`. This loads your changes into the current shell.

Now you are able to use the environment variable and every request goes through the HTTPS server.

There might some cases where he environment variable not works. Here you should use `iptables` to redirect your requests.